# Adding and Activate an existing plugin to your custom Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom Wordpress theme and I would like to ship it with an additional plugin and make it activated. I am very new to Wordpress and I have been looking at several resources online, but I am still unsure how to go about this. My understanding is that you would add in the functions.php the following:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'the_plugin_I_want' );
function the_plugin_I_want(){
}
```

My question is how to I "embed" the plugin as part of the theme I am shipping without having the actual plugins (php and .js files) in my plugin folder in wordpress (wordpress\wp-content\plugins). Can I achieve this?

Thanks,

I.

Comment: have a look at this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179148/65855

Comment: Thanks, had a look at it, but made me wonder whether for the described solution I still need to have the plugin in the WordPress folder. Can you clarify that? Also noticed that one person said that there is no way to bundle a plugin to a theme.